# Is there a notion of symplectic maps between spaces of volume forms on phase spaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, hamiltonian-mechanics

For a $n$ dimensional smooth manifold $M$, I consider the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ with [the canonical symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_bundle#The_cotangent_bundle_as_phase_space) form $\omega$.
A [symplectic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) $\phi : T^*M \to T^* M$ is a map which leaves the symplectic form invariant, i.e. $\phi^* \omega = \omega$.

**Question:**
Is there a notion of symplectic maps between the spaces of volume forms over the phase space $T^*M$?

*edit:*

In more detail: Let me denote the space of all volume forms over $T^*M$ as $\Omega^{2n}(T^*M) := \Gamma( \Lambda^{2n} (T^*M) )$ (the notation is from John M. Lee's book 'Intro to smooth manifolds'.)
Then for a map $\psi$ which transforms volume forms, i.e.
$$\psi : \mathrm{\Omega}^{2n}(T^*M) \to \mathrm{\Omega}^{2n}(T^*M),$$
I am looking for a condition which ensures that $\psi$ is compatible with the symplectic structure of $T^*M$?

*Example:*
A symplectic map $\phi : T^* M \to T^*M$ implies a map $$\psi : \mathrm{\Omega}^{2n}(T^*M) \to \mathrm{\Omega}^{2n}(T^*M) : \eta \mapsto \phi^* \eta.$$
Such a map should be compatible for example.

But I would expect that there are more maps which are compatible and that not all of them are derived from symplectic maps like in the example.

---

*Background:*
For numerical simulation of Hamiltonian equations, it is good to use symplectic integrators, such as symplectic Euler.
However, I am interested in solving [Liouville's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)#Liouville_equations) and this raised the question what a corresponding symplectic integrator would be in that case?

Comment: I suppose you mean by $\Omega^n(T^*M)$ the $n$-th antisymmetric tensor power of $T^*M$. This is a vector bundle of fiber dimension one over $M$. So the total space has dimension $n+1$. This makes it very unlikely to be symplectic (in ca half of all cases)

Comment: I want to look at volume forms in the phase space, so it should be the $n$-th antisymmetric tensor power of $T^*(T^*M)$. (Otherwise, I am also happy with an answer for a general symplectic manifold $X$ in the role of $T^*M$.)

I understand that such a map $\varphi$ is never symplectic in the original sense. My question is if there is a condition which ensures that the map is at least "compatible with the symplectic form on $T^*M$".  [I edited the question]

Comment: But $\Omega^{2n}(T^*M)$ is the space of volume forms on $T^*M$.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Is $\psi$ a vector bundle automorphism of the volume form bundle on $T^*M$? Or is it a map on sections of that bundle?

Comment: It should be a map on sections of that bundle.

Comment: A couple of questions for clarification: First, is it important that the underlying symplectic manifold is the total space of a cotangent bundle? I can't see why you question requires this. Second, since a symplectomorphism preserves the volume form, its induced action on $\Omega^{2n}$ is the identity. So what does it mean for a self-map on $\Omega^{2n}$ to be compatible with the symplectic structure? Perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: Ah, I see in the comment above that you don't particularly care that the symplectic manifold is a cotangent bundle.

Comment: @PaulReynolds I'm no a differential geometer, it might be trivial! (The feedback already helped me a lot!)
1. Yes, the cotangent bundle structure is not important for me. 2. As far as I know, symplectomorphisms preserve the canonical volume form $\omega^{\wedge n}$ but not arbitrary volume forms. (In the application, the volume forms represent densities of particles and they are not related to the canonical volume form at all.)

Comment: You're correct though, my assertion that a symplectomorphism preserves _all_ volume forms is not right. Perhaps you are interested in the diffeomorphisms that preserve $\omega^n$, with no further conditions, of which there are many.

Comment: @PaulReynolds Yes, that's a good point. I was hoping for some stronger conditions, but it could be that it's just this.